# Converting nvarchar to int for adding subtotal row in query results

Tags: sql-server-2014

I am trying to add a subtotal row to my query results where I'm trying to count the "Y" values by school in the results which in this case they are per the where clause logic.  In googling I understand that I need to convert my II.ApprovedByPrincipal to an INT value which is what I did in the FIRST select and then did a COUNT in the SECOND select from the UNION ALL statement but I get this error:

Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Y' to data type int.

Any help/direction on how to accomplish this would be appreciated, thanks.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT II.EnrolledSchool, II.syear, II.student_id, II.last_name, II.first_name,
    II.AddressSchool, II.Income_SchoolYear, II.NumberInHousehold, 
    II.HouseholdMember, II.PayType, II.Income, II.AddedOn, II.AddedBy,
    II.CompletedEarlyChildhoodDocumentation, CAST(II.ApprovedByPrincipal as int) as ApprovedByPrincipal, II.ApprovedByEarlyChildhood,
    QI.QualifyingInfo_SchoolYear, QI.MethodOfQualifying, QI.Notes, QI.ApprovedBy, QI.ApprovedDate
FROM II
INNER JOIN QI
ON II.student_id = QI.student_id
WHERE II.ApprovedByPrincipal IS NOT NULL
AND II.ApprovedByEarlyChildhood IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT II.EnrolledSchool+' Subtotal', null, null, null, null,
    null, null, null,
    null, null, null, null, null,
    null, count(II.ApprovedByPrincipal), null,
    null, null, null, null, null
FROM II
INNER JOIN QI
ON II.student_id = QI.student_id
WHERE II.ApprovedByPrincipal IS NOT NULL
AND II.ApprovedByEarlyChildhood IS NULL
GROUP BY II.EnrolledSchool
ORDER BY II.EnrolledSchool asc, II.last_name asc, II.first_name asc
```

Comment: `CAST(II.ApprovedByPrincipal as int)` ... why are you doing this?  I think this is the source of the error.

Comment: Because I cannot count a nvarchar data type column.and my understanding is that I have to convert this column to an INT data type in order to count it.  No?  I get the same error when I don't use the CAST either.

Comment: I am pretty sure that `CAST` is the culprit.  `COUNT` counts records, not integers, so casting there is not needed at all.  Are you sure that you ran the updated query without the cast?

Comment: Yes, I did remove the CAST and maintained the COUNT in the 2nd SELECT for the subtotal row.  The count is where the error is occurring because it cannot convert the nvarchar data type to an INT.